# The Inno Setup Runhidden flag is not working, how do I make it work?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I have wrapped up my django project using pyinstaller and later used [Inno Setup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inno_Setup) to make installer. Since django command prompt running background looks ugly, I use the runhidden flag in [Inno Setup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inno_Setup).

But when I click on desktop icon the application starts running by hiding the command prompt, and when I run it again without closing the previously opened app then the command prompt becomes visible.

I want to make command prompt always hidden. For more details have a look on my ISS script:

```
[Run]
Filename:  "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "Start Crumbs For table"; Flags: waituntilidle postinstall runhidden skipifsilent
```